# Change estimate shipping country programatically

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, shipping, quote, estimate

I want to change the country in estimate shipping (cart page) programatically in my module (meaning user clicks on a button in footer on homepage and I change the shipping country on cart page for that session):

[image]

However it doesn't work if I do it with the session object.

```
// Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

$quote = $this->session->getQuote()
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId('GB')->save();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId() // returns GB which is right, but the sidebar on frontend is still showing US on refresh.
```

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be done with js. Something like:

```
var countryData = customerData.get('checkout-data');
            if (countryData()) {
                if (countryData().shippingAddressFromData) {
                    countryData().shippingAddressFromData.country_id = "GB";
                } else {
                    countryData().shippingAddressFromData = {};
                    countryData().shippingAddressFromData.country_id = "US;
                }
                customerData.set('checkout-data', countryData());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be $quote->setShippingAddress()->getCountryId()->save();

Comment: not working, tried also  $quote->setShippingAddress()->setCountryId("GB")->save()

Answer (score 0):

use this:
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCountryId("GB")->save()